# Moderator SE proposal has reached the commitment stage; may be interesting for 10k users and others

Tags: discussion, area51

The area51 proposal for moderators SE is off to a running start with 15 commits in the first half hour. If you are interested commiting (meaning you ask/answer 10 questions in the beta when it starts), follow this link:http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52070/moderators?referrer=lvCPZ4QU5cfO5cdJcWCK1A2 or go to area51 and search for 'moderators'.